# Checking if local files are available

Tags: javascript, file, local

```
<script>
        var test;

    function gameExists() {
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open('HEAD', "/flappy.html", false);
    http.send();
    if(http.status!=404){
        test= "true";
    }else{
        test == "false";
    }

}
    </script>

<script>
if(test=="true") {
    alert('Game exists, add some code.');
} else {
    alert('Download Game !');
$('#frame').append('<a href="path/to/flappy.html">Download</a>');}

</script>
```

This is my javascript, to check if a local file is available. This is
being hosted locally so I can not use any server side languages. So I
am not sure what I have done wrong. Please help me, make this work. A)
It doesn't check correctly B) It doesn't download . Thank you :)
I am not sure why this code is not currently working, please help me
out! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Without even really looking at the code: use true and false, not "true" and "false". Furthermore it should be `test = false` not `test == "false"`

Answer (score 1):

Couple of issues:

1) You're trying to access `/flappy.html`, which on a local machine, is not what you want - it's literally the root of your machine. You're probably looking for a relative path, so use `flappy.html`. This is your main issue here.

2) You don't actually invoke the function. You need to call `gameExists()` before you check the result of `test`

3) Use `true` and `false`, not `"true"` and `"false"`.

4) It should be `test = false` not `test == "false"`. The first is an assignment, the second is a comparison.

You may also be interested in using jQuery's AJAX instead of the XMLRequest, since you clearly have included jQuery already. You'll need to use a callback to run the bottom half of your code, but with JSONP, you can make cross-domain requests.